# Why related table values comes null on HttpContext.Session.Get using List<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm developing a shopping Cart (using MVC Asp.Net Core 2.2 and EF).

Have 3 tables (Model class):

- Produto;
- Tamanho (related to Produto table);
- TipoMassa (related to Produto table).

In a ProductController class, I've created a List that is stored in a Session to get this list in a CartController class.

But, when I try to get that list in a CartController class, the values from the related tables (Tamanho and TipoMassa) are null. The list comes just with the Produto table values.

How can I fix it?

### Produto Controller class

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(IFormCollection collection)
{
    string Nome = collection["Nome"];
    byte IdTamanho = Convert.ToByte(collection["IdTamanho"]);
    byte IdTipoMassa = Convert.ToByte(collection["IdTipoMassa"]);


    var produtoContext = _context.Produto
            .Include(c => c.IdCategoriaNavigation)
            .Include(c => c.IdTamanhoNavigation)
            .Include(c => c.IdTipoMassaNavigation)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nome == Nome && p.IdTamanho == IdTamanho
        && p.IdTipoMassa == IdTipoMassa);

    if (produtoContext == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Add itens na Sesssion
    List<Produto> itens = new List<Produto>();
    itens = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Produto>>("itens");
    if (itens == null)
    {
        itens = new List<Produto>();
    }

    itens.Add(produtoContext);
    HttpContext.Session.Set("itens", itens);
    TempData["save"] = "Adicionado com sucesso";

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Produto");
}
```

- Works fine!
  But at the [CartController] IdCategoriaNavigation, IdTamanhoNavigation and IdTipoMassaNavigation comes null. Code below.

### Shopping Cart Controller class

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Produto> itens = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Produto>>
            ("itens");
    if (itens == null)
    {
        itens  = new List<Produto>();
    }
    return View(itens.ToList());
}
```

- When I try to show the values in a View, the related tables values (IdCategoriaNavigation, IdTamanhoNavigation and IdTipoMassaNavigation) are null. Code below.

### ShoppingCart View

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  <tr>
      <td>
          <small class="text-muted"> 2x </small>
      </td>
      <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
           <br />
           <small class="text-muted">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)</small>
  
            @if (item.IdCategoria == 1)
            {
              <small class="text-dark font-italic">
                  <label for="idTamanho"> 
                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdTamanhoNavigation)
                  </label>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdTamanhoNavigation.Valor)
              </small>

              <small class="text-dark font-italic">
                    <label for="idTamanho"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IdTipoMassaNavigation)</label>
                      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdTipoMassaNavigation.Valor)
              </small>
             }
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
             2x R$ @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
        </td>
        <td class="align-content-end">
             <a asp-controller="Produto" asp-action="RemoveFromCart" asp-route-id="@item.IdProduto" class="text-white">
                 <i class="fa fa-times text-info"></i>
             </a>
        </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

### Produto Model class

```
public partial class Produto
{
    public Produto()
    {
        Cardapio = new HashSet<Cardapio>();
        ItensPedido = new HashSet<ItensPedido>();
        Promocao = new HashSet<Promocao>();
    }

    public int IdProduto { get; set; }
    public int IdCategoria { get; set; }
    public byte IdTamanho { get; set; }
    public byte IdTipoMassa { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
    public bool IsAtivo { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Categoria IdCategoriaNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Tamanho IdTamanhoNavigation { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual TipoMassa IdTipoMassaNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cardapio> Cardapio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItensPedido> ItensPedido { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Promocao> Promocao { get; set; }
}
```

### Tamanho Model class

```
public partial class Tamanho
{
    public Tamanho()
    {
        Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    public byte IdTamanho { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }
}
```

### TipoMassa Model class

```
public partial class TipoMassa
{
    public TipoMassa()
    {
        Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    public byte IdTipoMassa { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show all the values in a ShoppingCart View.

Comment: Try to do Session.Add instead of Session.Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, I believe the problem simply with the lambda function:

Instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdTamanhoNavigation)
                              ^^^
```

you need to reference the correct input parameter (modelItem):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.IdTamanhoNavigation)
                                 ^^^
```

Comment: @peter Thanks Phillip, was my mistake trying to solve the problem. But the "main problem is" getting the List from the session on the ShoppingCart controller that still coming with the related navigations values null.

Comment: @GutoBarroso Do you mean the foreach (var item in Model) is giving you a NullReference error? is 'item' null? or is the item.IdTamanhoNavigation null?

Comment: The problem supose to be with Parent/Child collections. The Parent collection items (item.IdTamanhoNavigation) gives me null. The Child collection items (item.IdTamanhoNavigation.Valor) gives me a NullReference error. Because  JsonConvert.SerializeObject  are not serializing the related tables values (Gives me a Self referencing loop detected about the childs collections).

Comment: Problem solved with PreservReferensHandling.Objects when serialize an object.  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to say that I have been using a JSon to serialize that List into a Session.
But I had to use [JsonIgnore] on those related methods on Produto Model class, 
if not, I get an error from Newtonsoft.Jason when include those related tables values.

As you can see bellow

### On ShoppingCart Controller class

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(IFormCollection collection)
{
    ...

    var produtoContext = _context.Produto
        .Include(c => c.IdCategoriaNavigation)
         ^^^^
        .Include(c => c.IdTamanhoNavigation)
         ^^^^
        .Include(c => c.IdTipoMassaNavigation)
         ^^^^
       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Nome == Nome && p.IdTamanho == IdTamanho 
    && p.IdTipoMassa == IdTipoMassa);

    ... 

    The produtoContex here, normally has all the values from the related tables.
        {PianoPizza.Models.Categoria} 
        {PianoPizza.Models.Tamanho}
        {PianoPizza.Models.TipoMassa}

        But when I set the List on Session I got the Json error.     

    HttpContext.Session.Set("itens", itens);
                        ^^^^
    ...
 }
```

> JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'Pianino.Models.Produto'. 
>   Path '[0].IdCategoriaNavigation.Produto'.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)

Even commenting the first include I have the same for IdTamanhoNavigation  and IdTipoMassaNavigation.

So, using [JsonIgnore] like below, I fix that error. By other side, those values become null when I get the List from Session on ShoppingCart Controller class.

### On Produto Model class

```
 [JsonIgnore]
 public virtual Categoria IdCategoriaNavigation { get; set; }
 [JsonIgnore]
 public virtual Tamanho IdTamanhoNavigation { get; set; }
 [JsonIgnore]
 public virtual TipoMassa IdTipoMassaNavigation { get; set; }
```

### On Utility class

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{

    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) :
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```